# Why does write(), write both the open workbook, and to outputstream, and how can i only write to existing workbook?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

If I do the following:

```
Path originalPath = Paths.get("src/test/resources/ORIGINAL.xlsm");
File originalFile = copyPath.toFile()
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(originalFile);
//Populate with some values
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("src/test/resources/TEST.xlsm");
workbook.write(fileOut);
```

Then both TEST.xlsm and ORIGINAL.xlsm will be populated with values

If I don't use `write()`, of course no `TEST.xlsm` will be created, but also nothing will be updated in `ORIGINAL.xlsm`

However if i do

```
workbook.write(System.out);
```

then
`ORIGINAL.xlsm` will be updated

Why is it so that write will write the workbook, it says nothing in the documentation about that?

> JavaDoc: "Write out this workbook to an Outputstream."

Is there any other way of **only** updating the ORIGINAL.xlsm?

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you facing this with?

Comment: That's an odd version to pick. What happens if you try the latest, 3.12-beta1? (Or wait a week or so, and try 3.12 final)